# Consulta sobre SINGLETON en c# (PRACTICA)

Tags: c#, poo, consola, app, singleton

Estoy practicando y adaptandome al lenguaje **C#**. Vengo de **DELPHI**. Aun asi, recien estoy empezando en esto de la programacion.

Queria hacer una consulta. Estoy practicando creando una app de consola. Esta APP desplegaria un MENU, donde segun leyendo un comando (string) que ingrese el usuario, ingrese  a un contexto (que es una clase que realizara sus respectivas tareas). Estas clases cada una esta dedicada a realizar alguna tarea en particular. Manejar clientes, manejar pagos etc.

Por lo tanto, cada clase contexto (deriva de una clase base llama BaseContext), la cual tiene un método virtual, llamado (EXECUTE) y donde es sobreescrita en cada subclase y tendrán su propio bucle y su propia implementacion.

Yo queria aplicar SINGLETON aquí para cada clase, puesto no necesito que estas clases de tipo (contexto) creen varias instancias, y es mas, diría que hasta utilizando métodos estáticos me valdría. Pero pierdo mucha flexibilidad usando métodos estáticos porque ni siquiera puedo usar interfaces, cosa que me vendría bien para practica. Es lo correcto usar **singleton** ? Ustedes que opinan.

Hago una pequeña muestra de lo que quiero hacer :

```
class BaseContext{
    public virtual void ContextExecute(){
            
            keyContextControl = true;
            SetMessage("Bienvenido al ambito de contexto base"); //escribe en consola texto
           
            
            while ( keyContextControl == true ) {
                ReadMessage();
                if (inMessage == "exit") {
                    keyContextControl = false;
                } else{
                    SetMessage("Ejecucion del codigo");
                    if (inMessage == "clients"){
                        BaseContext ClientAmbience = new ClientsContext();
                    }
                }
            }

            SetMessage("Usted esta saliendo del ambito de contexto base");
        }
}

    class ClientsContext // con su propio metodo execute
    class PayContext // con su propio metodo execute
    class Administrator // con su propio metodo execute
```

Comment: 1.- Lamentablemente este sitio no permite preguntas y respuestas que sean opiniones. 2.- Y aunque fueran validas tu pregunta carece de un contexto, porque un singleton es útil para algunos casos y para otros no, y en tu caso es imposible saberlo.

Comment: 3.- Pero para intentar aportar algo, un singleton es una única instancia de un objeto, y a su vez una instancia es algo que se almacena en memoria, y si tu quieres algo permanente en la memoria es porque vas a necesitar mantener el estado (es decir, mantener valores en variables y propiedades), entonces si tu función `ContextExecute` es agnóstica de cualquier estado, simplemente debe ser una función estática, caso contrario podría ser que un singleton fuera solución. Por último, no todo objeto que se instancia una sola vez debe ser un singleton,

Comment: "Si tu quieres algo permanente en la memoria es porque vas a necesitar mantener el estado" -> No es cierto @Yussef. Es práctica común crear algunas clases como singletons simplemente para no tener que instanciarlas una y otra vez, puesto que el proceso de instanciación puede provocar picos de consumo totalmente innecesarios y ciertas clases sin estado y que van a servir de "proxy" de otras cosas, como servicios o repositorios que no deberían tener nunca estado, si se mantienen instanciados. A veces como singletons, otras simplemente en un contexto superior en alguna lista de servicios.

Comment: El problema de dejar estatico el metodo ContextExecute() es que no lo puedo sobreescribir en clases derivadas. Si quiero dejarlo virtual y sobreescribirlo, debo.usarlo como metodo de instancia. Podria resolverlo de varias maneras, pero lo que yo queria saber era si era aplicable el singleton aqui como.para practicar el uso de patrones.

Comment: @LeandroPalavecino, deberías preguntarte si el patrón singleton va a aportar alguna ventaja significativa a tu aplicación o si sólo va a complicar más las cosas sin apenas beneficio. ¿Por qué no simplemente instanciar la clase que corresponda en el momento adecuado y ya está, sin más complicaciones?